# Usage of would have

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, would

While reading a document I came across the following sentence:
"After 9 months’ time data base administrator will run a job which will copy record from operational to archival data base and as soon as it is completed, **we would have** moved all the data in the archival data base together with it being removed from the operational one"

What the sentence wants to convey is that after the job is done the data will be moved to archival database and deleted from the operational database. What I want to know is that does **would have** convey this or this is not its correct usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be.

Grammatically correct options:

> as soon as it is completed, **we will move** all the data in the archival data base together with it being removed from the operational one

or

> ***by the time*** it is completed, **we would have** moved all the data in the archival data base together with it being removed from the operational one

The second sentence implies the data moving happens simultaneously and will be finished by the time your job is done. Since this is not what is meant to be conveyed, I'd stick with the first option.

EDIT: Since the actions described after 'would have' are consequences of the job itself, the usage of 'would have' may be passable here, but it doesn't go well with 'as soon as'.

I'd paraphrase it as simply:

> ***when*** it is completed, **we would have** moved all the data in the archival data base together with it being removed from the operational one

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but the data transfer as well as the deletion happen because of the job that is being run. This is the purpose of the job. So can you also elaborate with this regard.

Comment: @SyedOsamaMaruf: Edited